# Adding an Image with a Title in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I would like to show a small icon next to the title in my UINavigationController.

Through the magic of Photoshop, like this:

[image]

I know I need to create a new view and build the image and title into it.  Here is what I am doing:

In viewDidLoad in the UINavigationController view controller, I call the method

`[self setTitleBar];`

Which calls this method:

```
- (void) setTitleBar {


    CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;


    //UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(navBarFrame.origin.x, navBarFrame.origin.y, (leftButtonFrame.origin.x + leftButtonFrame.size.width) - rightButtonFrame.origin.x, navBarFrame.size.height)];
    UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(navBarFrame.origin.x, navBarFrame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,navBarFrame.size.height)];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    CGPoint tvCenter = CGPointMake(titleView.frame.size.width/2, titleView.frame.size.height/2);

    UIImage * icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star"];

    UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:icon];
    iconView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, icon.size.width, icon.size.height);

    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    title.text = @"SOME TITLE";
    title.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, titleView.frame.size.height);
    [title sizeToFit];


    iconView.center = CGPointMake(tvCenter.x - (icon.size.width/2), tvCenter.y);

    [titleView addSubview:iconView];
    [titleView addSubview:title];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
}
```

My logic in the titleView is: Get the left most button's frame and get the right most buttons frame. THEN do some math to figure out how big the view can be. That should be the titleView's frame size.

However, I can't seem to get it to work. If I plug in a frame size of 0,0,100,40; then it shows the frame but everything is squished together. But you see it. I know that 100 should be dynamic to ensure that the title is shown.

But I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help?

Comment: Use `sizeToFit`. Here is the documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit?language=objc.

Comment: Does the navigation bar auto-resize your view? If so, maybe you should make this in a XIB so that you can easily see what it looks like when it's resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can place objects on the Navigation Controller View, as subviews.

```
- (void) setTitleBar {

    //Let's say your icon size is 20
    int starSize = 20;
    //Now you'll have to calculate where to place the ImageView respect the TextSize (for this you'll need to know the text and font of your UINavigationItem title)
    CGSize textSize = [@"SOME TITLE" sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"navfontname" size:15]}];
    UIImageView *startImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width/2 - textSize.width/2, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height/2 - starSize/2, starSize,starSize)];
    startImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star"];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:startImageView];

}
```

Comment: hmmm.. I can't seem to get this to work. Seems logical though

Comment: Is it the UIImageView added as a subview to the self.navigationController.view? can you see it if you set up its frame to something like CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)?

Comment: It places it in the middle of the screen.